# Ansible how to ignore whitespace while reading variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the below variables declared.

```
condition: false
old_domain: old.com
new_domain: old.com
domain: >-
   {{
      old_domain
      if condition
      else
      new_domain
   }}
```

And in the template I have if condition as:

```
{% if domain != old_domain %}
domains are not the same
{% else %}
domains are same
{% endif %}
```

Expected output:

```
domains are same
```

But getting:

```
domains are not the same
```

I observed there is an extra space coming for the `domain` variable which is causing condition failure. How can I read a variable and ignore whitespace something like `domain|trim`.

Note: I am able to get the expected output by changing the `domain` var to the below syntax but I don't want to change the variable format here.

```
domain: {{ old_domain if condition  else new_domain }}
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/8b5f6379bd0cb6dd5c09b7ae78e43bd8)

Comment: Have you tried to `debug` the value of `domain`? What value does it get?

Comment: ```domain``` value is ```old.com```.

Comment: @Zeitounator I tested your code, It's working. But can you try copy-pasting exactly the variables from the question. both looks same but myn not working.

Comment: Instead of inline jina it woule be better to use *ternary* filter, generally whitespaces could be remove with *strip* filter. Example: `{{ (condition) | ternary(old_domain, new_domain) }}`. `foo: " bar "` -> `foo.strip()`.

Comment: Thanks, @JiriB Good to know about this filter. I am trying to find problem in the present code and especially ignoring whitespace for variables.

Comment: @SNR You simply have three trailing spaces after the double closing mustache (that my IDE stripped automatically when I tried to reproduce).

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for finding out the problem. I'm trying to avoid these accidental mistakes by stripping down whitespace from a variable, ais there any option for it ?

Comment: Self-explanatory one liner for you to try `ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg='raw: {{ test_var }}. Trimmed: {{ test_var | trim }}'" -e "test_var='   content    '"`

Comment: @Zeitounator ```trim``` is actually seems working. I should accept this as the answer. And I couldn't find this in ansible docs. This <https://cloudaffaire.com/functions-in-ansible/> has useful info

Comment: When it comes to filters in ansible, you should always check the ansible documentation AND the [jinja2 documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#trim)

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
' '.join(your_var.split())|trim
```

It will remove any spaces between and outside your string variable.